# An example of unitary matrix which is $3\times 3$ and complex

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

Please give me an example of unitary matrix which is $3\times 3$ and complex. If I get this example, i will finish my thesis.

Answer (score 2):

A matrix with $\imath$ on the diagonal, since $\imath \overline{\imath} = 1$.
Or a Discrete Fourier transform matrix:
$$ D = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & \jmath & \overline{\jmath}\\
1 & \overline{\jmath} & \jmath
\end{bmatrix}
$$
with $\jmath$ the standard complex root of unity: $\jmath = e^{2\pi \imath/3}$

Comment: That is okey but what about other elements?

Comment: @Murat You should have asked that before in you question. I have edited my answed to avoid $0$

Answer (score 1):

Is this sufficient?

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
i & 0 & 0\\
0 & i & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

or  the matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}
\sqrt{1/3}+i\sqrt{1/3} & \sqrt{1/6} - i\sqrt{1/6}  &  0\\
-i\sqrt{1/6} & \sqrt{1/3} & \sqrt{1/6} +i\sqrt{1/3}\\
\sqrt{1/6} & i\sqrt{1/3} & \sqrt{1/3}-i\sqrt{1/6}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which can be found [here](https://carlbrannen.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/a-new-parameterization-for-3x3-unitary-matrices/).

Comment: I'm looking a matrix which is not include much zero

Comment: Just take this one and rotate it into another coordinate frame.

Comment: How can I rotate it?

Comment: @thanasissdr there are lots of zero i need zero maximum 3 times.

Comment: @thanasissdr thank you sir

Comment: @Murat You are welcome!